# How to install the diagnostic_msgs config file?

Tags: ros, roomba, catkin, raspberrypi, create-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to use my raspi3 to control the roomba641. I followed the guide in https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy to install the create_autonomy in my raspi with raspbian and ros indigo. I made a new catkin workspace, and cloned the package in the src folder. I just followed the step wrote in the github and failed in the "catkin build" step. It seems that all the packages except ca_driver successfully built.
It said:

```
"CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "diagnostic_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    diagnostic_msgsConfig.cmake
    diagnostic_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "diagnostic_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "diagnostic_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "diagnostic_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)"
```

It seems that the problem is lack of diagnostic_msgs. Then, I sudo apt-get install ros-diagnostic_msgs. Again, the same error.
What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279508/how-to-install-the-diagnostic_msgs-config-file?/) by [Hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/32901/hunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a typical Problem if you have missing dependencies.

Installing `ros-diagnostic_msgs` should have thrown an error. There is no such packet.
You need to install `ros-<distro>-diagnostic-msgs` (note the dashes instead of underscores, and the distro, for you this should be `ros-indigo-diagnostic-msgs`.

If the package you want to compile is set up correctly, you could also do a `rosdep install <my_package>` to automatically install the required packages.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/32901/hunter/) on 2018-01-11**:
When I do sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-diagnostic-msgs, it said:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-diagnostic-msgs

But it is successful if I run ros-diagnostic-msgs. Which one is correct?

**Comment by [Hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/32901/hunter/) on 2018-01-11**:
It seems that because I run this command(sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-diagnostic-msgs) on a raspi instead of PC. I also tried this command on my PC, it works.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-11**:
Does it work with `ros-diagnostic-msgs` then? This is strange. Please provide some details on OS and how you set up ROS.

**Comment by [Hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/32901/hunter/) on 2018-01-15**:
Basically, I followed this guide http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi to build ros indigo on my raspbian. However, I am a beginner, I may pass some steps in 3.2 about dependencies. However, finally, the ros indigo was successfully installed on my raspi.

**Comment by [Hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/32901/hunter/) on 2018-01-15**:
After I installed ros-diagnostic-msgs, it still can not work. I cloned this in the new catkin build workspace(followed the provided github link). Is the problem related to the workspace?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-15**:
after you clone, you obviously need compile as well. Did you do that and was this successfull?
Otherwise, you can try to resolve the depenency with `rosdep` (see 3.2.2).

Another possibility is to use the `Ubuntu Mate` Image for the raspberry, which works like a charm,

**Comment by [Hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/32901/hunter/) on 2018-01-16**:
Thank you. Finally, I changed to ubuntu mate with ros kinetic, and It works with no error.